# filter(condition) syntax doesn't work after migration to SOLR 8.3

Tags: solr, solr8

We are migrating an application from SOLR 4.6 to 8.3, and one problem came up today - the following query runs fine in SOLR 4.6 but returns no results in 8.3.

`https://solr.url/select?q=*&fq=(-sample_sampletype:NUCLEIC_ACID+AND+-concept_sampletype:BACTERIA)`

When I rewrite it as two separate `fq` parameters

`fq=-sample_sampletype:NUCLEIC_ACID&fq=-concept_sampletype:BACTERIA`

it starts working correctly, so data is not an issue.

According to the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/common-query-parameters.html#fq-filter-query-parameter), the filter(condition) syntax is still supported in 8.3 so I am confused why the original query is not working (returns an empty result set).

Comment: What is your goal? To remove those that have either `sample_sampletype:NUCLEIC_ACID` or `concent_sampletype=BACTERIA` set, or those that have both values present?

Comment: @matslindh to remove those from search results

Comment: Yes, but are you looking at removing those documents that have both fields, and only those, or those who have either of those (and not necessarily both)?

Comment: @MatsLindh I need to filter out documents where both conditions are true at the same time. My question is why the existing query works in SOLR 4 but doesn't work in SOLR 8. We have several legacy applications that make these types of queries, and having to update them is next to impossible for various reasons. So I am looking to figure out if there is anything I can change on SOLR side to make it work. Documentation says that this query fq=(cond1 cond2) shoudl work in SOLR 8, but it doesn't

Comment: Negative queries need to subtract from something; I'd start by prefixing your query with `*:*` - so either `*:* (-sample_sampletype:NUCLEIC_ACID AND -concept_sampletype:BACTERIA)` or `*:* -(sample_sampletype:NUCLEIC_ACID AND concept_sampletype:BACTERIA)`. The last one might work without `*:*` in front of it, since it's a pure negative query on the top level`

Comment: @MatsLindh I have q=* in the same query, it should do it, no?

Comment: No, the `fq` will create it's own set which is then intersected with the set returned from the query. If the set generated by the query inside `fq` is empty, no documents will be returned.